# How do you create a .gz file using PHP?

Tags: php, compression, gzip

I would like to gzip compress a file on my server using PHP.  Does anyone have an example that would input a file and output a compressed file?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The other answers here load the entire file into memory during compression, which will cause '*out of memory*' errors on large files.  The function below should be more reliable on large files as it reads and writes files in 512kb chunks.

```
/**
 * GZIPs a file on disk (appending .gz to the name)
 *
 * From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073397/how-do-you-create-a-gz-file-using-php
 * Based on function by Kioob at:
 * http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzwrite.php#34955
 * 
 * @param string $source Path to file that should be compressed
 * @param integer $level GZIP compression level (default: 9)
 * @return string New filename (with .gz appended) if success, or false if operation fails
 */
function gzCompressFile($source, $level = 9){ 
    $dest = $source . '.gz'; 
    $mode = 'wb' . $level; 
    $error = false; 
    if ($fp_out = gzopen($dest, $mode)) { 
        if ($fp_in = fopen($source,'rb')) { 
            while (!feof($fp_in)) 
                gzwrite($fp_out, fread($fp_in, 1024 * 512)); 
            fclose($fp_in); 
        } else {
            $error = true; 
        }
        gzclose($fp_out); 
    } else {
        $error = true; 
    }
    if ($error)
        return false; 
    else
        return $dest; 
}
```

*UPDATE:* Gerben has posted an improved version of this function that is cleaner and uses exceptions instead of returning false on an error. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140427/195835

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.

Comment: Very good bit of code. I took the above and created the reverse to decompress a file. The code is fairly quick.

Answer (score 105):

This code does the trick

```
// Name of the file we're compressing
$file = "test.txt";

// Name of the gz file we're creating
$gzfile = "test.gz";

// Open the gz file (w9 is the highest compression)
$fp = gzopen ($gzfile, 'w9');

// Compress the file
gzwrite ($fp, file_get_contents($file));

// Close the gz file and we're done
gzclose($fp);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will probably read the entire file into memory, possibly hitting PHP's memory limit on large files. :-(

Comment: while w9 is the highest compression ? which is lowest compression, just for packing data in .gz ?

Comment: @SimonEast hit the point. This function will hit your memory limit on big files (and you know what? gzip is used to compress that kind of big files). The good answer is the one above not this one

Answer (score 23):

Also, you could use php's [wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php), the [compression ones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php). With a minimal change in the code you would be able to switch between gzip, bzip2 or zip.

```
$input = "test.txt";
$output = $input.".gz";

file_put_contents("compress.zlib://$output", file_get_contents($input));
```

change `compress.zlib://` to <strike>`compress.zip://` for zip compression</strike> *(see comment to this answer about zip compression)*, or to `compress.bzip2://` to bzip2 compression.

Comment: I think `compress.zip://` is not supported for compression. See note on http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

Comment: @Alex yes, it seems you are right, and the zip:// wrapper does not support writing nor appending to an already existing file

Answer (score 7):

Simple one liner with [gzencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php):

```
gzencode(file_get_contents($file_name));
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this pointer. This useful answer has led me to a whole series of **Zlib functions**: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.zlib.php

Answer (score 4):

Here's an improved version. I got rid of all the nested if/else statements, resulting in lower cyclomatic complexity, there's better error handling through exceptions instead of keeping track of a boolean error state, some type hinting and I'm bailing out if the file has a gz extension already. It got a little longer in terms of lines of code, but it's much more readable.

```php
/**
 * Compress a file using gzip
 *
 * Rewritten from Simon East's version here:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754032/3499843
 *
 * @param string $inFilename Input filename
 * @param int    $level      Compression level (default: 9)
 *
 * @throws Exception if the input or output file can not be opened
 *
 * @return string Output filename
 */
function gzcompressfile(string $inFilename, int $level = 9): string
{
    // Is the file gzipped already?
    $extension = pathinfo($inFilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($extension == "gz") {
        return $inFilename;
    }

    // Open input file
    $inFile = fopen($inFilename, "rb");
    if ($inFile === false) {
        throw new \Exception("Unable to open input file: $inFilename");
    }

    // Open output file
    $gzFilename = $inFilename.".gz";
    $mode = "wb".$level;
    $gzFile = gzopen($gzFilename, $mode);
    if ($gzFile === false) {
        fclose($inFile);
        throw new \Exception("Unable to open output file: $gzFilename");
    }

    // Stream copy
    $length = 512 * 1024; // 512 kB
    while (!feof($inFile)) {
        gzwrite($gzFile, fread($inFile, $length));
    }

    // Close files
    fclose($inFile);
    gzclose($gzFile);

    // Return the new filename
    return $gzFilename;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gerben. Yes, your version is cleaner, and I agree that exceptions are better here.

Comment: Super work, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to just unzip a file, this works and doesn't cause issues with memory:

```
$bytes = file_put_contents($destination, gzopen($gzip_path, r));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably obvious to many, but if any of the program execution functions is enabled on your system (`exec`, `system`, `shell_exec`), you can use them to simply `gzip` the file.

```
exec("gzip ".$filename);
```

**N.B.:** Be sure to properly sanitize the `$filename` variable before using it, especially if it comes from user input (but not only). It may be used to run arbitrary commands, for example by containing something like `my-file.txt && anothercommand` (or `my-file.txt; anothercommand`).

Comment: exec is locked down on most hosting platforms and is a security risk in general to even use exec

Comment: @Wranorn That's why I indicated “if any of the program execution functions is enabled on your system,” should I have written “on your hosting platform” instead? As for the security, if you don't pass user input to this function, I'm not sure what is the risk. The only warnings in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) are about using `escapeshellarg()` or `escapeshellcmd()` when passing user-supplied data to the function.

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer for linux servers for own custom projects. If this function uses inside if project without user interactions, for example by cron - it secure for 100%

Answer (score 0):

copy('file.txt', 'compress.zlib://' . 'file.txt.gz');
See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php#120583)

Answer (score 0):

Compress folder for anyone needs

```
function gzCompressFile($source, $level = 9)
{
    $tarFile = $source . '.tar';

    if (is_dir($source)) {
        $tar = new PharData($tarFile);
        $files = scandir($source);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (is_file($source . '/' . $file)) {
                $tar->addFile($source . '/' . $file, $file);
            }
        }
    }

    $dest = $tarFile . '.gz';
    $mode = 'wb' . $level;
    $error = false;
    if ($fp_out = gzopen($dest, $mode)) {
        if ($fp_in = fopen($tarFile, 'rb')) {
            while (!feof($fp_in))
                gzwrite($fp_out, fread($fp_in, 1024 * 512));
            fclose($fp_in);
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
        gzclose($fp_out);
        unlink($tarFile);
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }
    if ($error)
        return false;
    else
        return $dest;
}
```