# Compress with gzip a created XML file

Tags: php, xml, gzip

For creating xml-files I use the DOMObject. But all the created xml-files are big and would cause a heavy bandwidth.

This is the way I save the xml-file

```
$xml->save($filename);
```

How could I add a gzip compression?

EDIT:
This snippet doesn't work because it creates an empty file

```
$gz = gzopen($filename,'w');
gzwrite($gz, $xml);
gzclose($gz);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzwrite.php

Comment: The gzopen() confuses me because until the saving process the file doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a .gz file using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073397/how-do-you-create-a-gz-file-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a .zip implementation.

```
$file   = '...';
$folder = 'folder';

$zip      = new ZipArchive();
$fileName = "some_file.zip";

if ($zip->open($fileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
     throw new Exception('Can not create zip file.');
}

$zip->addEmptyDir($folder);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $zip->addFile($file, $folder . "/" . basename($file));
}

$zip->close();
```

Comment: I solved it with $xml->save('compress.zlib://' . $filename . '.gz');

Comment: @Ronny Linsener: That's the correct way and you find this asked and answered here: [How do you create a .gz file using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6073397/367456) - I therefore voted to close against the duplicate to make the relation more tight.