# How to compress a file say xxx.xml of 6MB into xxx.xml.gz using php program

Tags: php, xml, compression, gzip

```
How to compress a file say xxx.xml of 6MB into xxx.xml.gz using php program.
```

[How do you create a .gz file using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073397/how-do-you-create-a-gz-file-using-php)

This solution doesn't work for me. it produce one .gz file which cant be open. it should be not just .gz it should be xxx.xml.gz

```
    $source='xxx.xml';

function gzCompressFile($source, $level = 9){ 
    $dest = $source . '.gz'; 
    $mode = 'wb' . $level; 
    $error = false; 
    if ($fp_out = gzopen($dest, $mode)) { 
        if ($fp_in = fopen($source,'rb')) { 
            while (!feof($fp_in)) 
                gzwrite($fp_out, fread($fp_in, 1024 * 512)); 
            fclose($fp_in); 
        } else {
            $error = true; 
        }
        gzclose($fp_out); 
    } else {
        $error = true; 
    }
    if ($error)
        return false; 
    else
        return $dest; 
} 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////compresion of output file ends here

//call gzCompressFile function starts

         gzCompressFile();

// call gzCompressFile function ends
```

The other solution below is only for string not for file.

```
     <?php
    $string = 'Some information to compress';
    $gz = gzopen('somefile.gz','w9');
    gzwrite($gz, $string);
    gzclose($gz);
    ?>
```

Above one is for only string compression not for file compression 
Kindly help me to fix it.

Comment: It's not limited to 512KB. Reread your link.

Comment: I implemented the link instead of getting xxx.xml.gz as output file generated in server. i get jut un openable .gz file

Comment: 6MB isn't a large file. You shouldn't need to even bother with splitting the files. See the second answer on the link.

Comment: You dont pass the filename to `gzCompressFile`

Comment: http://php.net/variables.scope

Comment: Thanks Charlotee Dunois  and Jon Stirling. It works after passing the filename along with path ,while calling the function