# How to gzip folder in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gzip, archive

I want to compress folder and it's content in Laravel project into gzip archive with highest possible compression level.

```
storage_path().'myFolder'
```

**It's not meant** to be transferred over HTTP so please don't get confused with server response gzip compression.

I just want an archive but didn't find info whether Laravel has any tool for the prurpose, any ideas?

Comment: Gzip is a stream compression format, it has no concept of files or directories. You need to use an archive format like tar and gzip that, or use a combination format like Zipfile.

Comment: /bin/bash ? `$ tar -zcf ./archive.tar.gz ./myFolder`. From php `shell_exec('tar -zcf [path_to]/archive.tar.gz [path_from]/myFolder')`

Comment: Or use http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a helper function for you.

```
if (!function_exists('gzip')) {
    function gzip($filename, $disk = 'local', $delete_original = false)
    {
        $disk = Storage::disk($disk);
        $data = $disk->get($filename);
        $out_file = "$filename.gz";

        $gzdata = gzencode($data, 9);
        $disk->put($out_file, $gzdata);
        $fp = fopen($disk->path($out_file), "w");
        $result = fwrite($fp, $gzdata);
        fclose($fp);

        if ($result && $delete_original) {
            $disk->delete($filename);
        }

        return $result > 0;

    }
}
```

Tested and working for me on laravel 7.x. Just make sure you have gzip compression enabled on your machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a Laravel specific issue to me. For normal zip compression, there are Laravel packages available (i.e. [`zanysoft/laravel-zip`](https://github.com/zanysoft/laravel-zip)), but for gzip you might want to have a look at the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073397/how-do-you-create-a-gz-file-using-php). To me it doesn't look like it requires an own package for the job.

By the way, you'd use `storage_path('myFolder')` in favour of `storage_path().'myFolder'`. This will concatenate the paths properly.